# How to get current HttpRequest quarkus?

Tags: quarkus

How to get current request in class ? I am using below code to inject code. but request is null

```
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;

@RequestScoped
public class BaseErrorCode {
    @Context
    HttpRequest request;
}
```

Comment: Which Quarkus RESTEasy extension are you using?

Comment: I am using below version . @geoand.
I am using below one. 
<dependency> 
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId> 
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId> 
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
     <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId> 
     <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId> 
</dependency>

Comment: Try to change RequestScoped annotation by "Provider". It works for me.

Comment: thanks @Luisao for your response. didn't work for . can you please share code?

```

@Provider
public class BaseErrorCode {
    @Context
    HttpRequest request;

    public String getHttpMethod() {
        return "GET";
    }

}

```

Answer (score 0):

I use in this way, i'm not sure if it will be valid for you:

```
@Provider
public class BaseErrorCode  implements ContainerRequestFilter{

    @Context 
    HttpRequest request;
    
    
    public String getHttpMethod() {
        return "GET";
    }


    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
```